# Conditions for Normal Approximation to Binomial

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

It is well known that if $np > 5$ and $n(1-p) > 5$ that a normal distribution with mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$ can be used to approximate a binomial distribution.

My question is, what happens if the conditions are not satisifed, but I still want to do an approximation. Is there some sort of adjustment I can use?

Comment: Another rule is that $np(1-p)>9$. Of course, you can approximate , if the rule is not satisfied, but the approximations might be "bad". I read from some interpolations that give better approximations, but I cannot remember the details.

Comment: If $n$ is small, it should be no problem to calculate the probabilities directly. If $n$ is large and WLOG $p\le 0.5$, we have two cases : If $p$ is near $0.5$, the normal approximation is well. If $p$ is small, the poisson-distribution is a well approximation.

Comment: You may want to consult the following reference: W. Molenaar, "Approximations to the Poisson, Binomial and Hypergeometric Distribution Functions". MC Tracts, Vol. 31, pp. 1-160. Amsterdam 1973 ([online](https://repository.cwi.nl/noauth/search/fullrecord.php?publnr=13049)). Chapter III covers normal approximations to the binomial distribution.

Comment: Even with large n there is typically no problem in getting the probabilities directly by using standard software software. In excel, the function BINOM.DIST can quickly find the wanted probabilities even if n is in the hundreds of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place your first claim is not really meaningful. Does it mean that if $np = n(1-p) = 5$ then a normal approximation to the binomial cannot be used? What about $4.9$? The point is that you need to specify what you mean by "approximate" before it makes proper sense. Furthermore, this claim is actually false if "approximate" means something like "within 10%" of the true value, since if $p = \frac5n$ then as $n \to \infty$ the binomial distribution tends (in the sense of its CDF) to the Poisson distribution instead, and not to the normal distribution, if I didn't remember wrongly.

That said, you are probably asking for a better approximation to the binomial distribution in the sense of having more higher-order terms. I don't know whether [the tail bounds on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds) would help you, since I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: If n is large, but np is small, the Poisson distribution is a good approximation.

Comment: @herbsteinberg: Apparently, you did not even read my post. I said **you need to specify what you mean by "approximate" before it makes proper sense**.