# How many items must be sampled to ensure normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, sampling

I was working on a problem that was dealing with proportions and it asked the following:

If a population proportion is believed to be $0.6$, how many items must be sampled to ensure that the sampling distribution of $\hat{p}$ will be approximately normal? Assume that the size of the population is $N = 10,000$.

I know that the Normal condition for a sampling distribution is $np\geq 10$ and $n(1-p)\geq 10$. I got that the answer was $25$ with this reasoning. The answer key says that it is 42. I am not sure what am I missing here. I computed $42\times 0.6=25.2$ but don't know if that is actually something I am supposed to use. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it should be noted that $npq=10.08$

Comment: Thank you. Am I suppose to use $npq \geq 10$?

Comment: As I say, I'm not sure. Maybe someone else seeing this question will know. That just seemed like a useful observation to make - perhaps that's the condition.

Comment: [As you’ll see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843560/conditions-for-normal-approximation-to-binomial) there is no one standard. If this is for a class, then check with your instructor which inequality they would like you to use.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be that $np>10$ and $np(1-p)>10$. This would give that $n>41 \frac{2}{3}$ which is probably what you want.